How do I create a singleton reference-type in Swift 6?
I wrote this for a little CLI tool I'm making. It's only important that it can receive & run its function calls immediately, because it's for logging, where placing the lines in-order is important.
import Foundation



fileprivate final class OutputCoordinator {
    
    private var output = String()
    
    
    private init() {}
    
    
    deinit {
        flushOutput()
    }
    
    
    func prepare(outputLine line: String) {
        output += line
        output += "\n"
    }
    
    
    func flushOutput() {
        defer { output = .init() }
        Swift.print(output)
    }
    
    
    
    static let shared = OutputCoordinator()
}



func print(queueing items: Any...) {
    let line = items.map(String.init(describing:)).joined(separator: " ")
    OutputCoordinator.shared.prepare(outputLine: line)
}

I work with warnings-as-errors, so it fails with this:
Static property 'shared' is not concurrency-safe because it is not either conforming to 'Sendable' or isolated to a global actor; this is an error in Swift 6

The only way I could figure out to get this to compile is with @unchecked Sendable:
fileprivate final class OutputCoordinator: @unchecked Sendable {

Surely this isn't the intended way the Swift language designers want me to do this. What should I be doing instead?

How do you use the code? For example use an actor rather than a class as suggested by the warning-error.

@vadian I use the code by calling print(queueing: "Some console message")

@Rob it's used for output purposes, as in stdout from a CLI command. I have my own solution to logging

The compiler is warning you that your type is not thread-safe. To indicate that it was thread-safe, we would make it Sendable. That means you would either:

Make it an actor:
actor OutputCoordinator {…}


Isolate it to some global actor, such as the main actor:
@MainActor
final class OutputCoordinator {…}

You could also create your own global actor for this, too. But, just making the type an actor (point 1, above) would be simpler.

Or manually make it Sendable:
final class OutputCoordinator: @unchecked Sendable {
    static let shared = OutputCoordinator()

    private var output = ""
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "output.coordinator")

    deinit {
        flushOutput()
    }

    func prepare(outputLine line: String) {
        queue.async { [self] in
            output += line
            output += "\n"
        }
    }

    func flushOutput() {
        queue.async { [self] in
            print(output)
            output = ""
        }
    }
}

Note, I generally would use locks for manual synchronization, but you suggested that FIFO behavior was important, so I have used a queue here. But given that you said that this is a single-threaded app, that’s not a concern, so I would probably do:
final class OutputCoordinator: @unchecked Sendable {
    static let shared = OutputCoordinator()

    private var output = ""
    private let lock = NSLock()

    deinit {
        flushOutput()
    }

    func prepare(outputLine line: String) {
        lock.withLock {
            output += line
            output += "\n"
        }
    }

    func flushOutput() {
        lock.withLock {
            print(output)
            output = ""
        }
    }
}



In general, when merely trying to eliminate data races, I would lean towards an actor. But given that you need strict FIFO behaviors (which actors do not guarantee), you might want to use the dispatch queue pattern.
Regardless, as I think you already guessed, the key is that you would never use @unchecked Sendable without actually synchronizing the internal state. The compiler is warning you that your original code snippet was not thread-safe, and you should never declare @unchecked Sendable conformance without actually making it thread-safe.

FWIW, to technically make this a “singleton”, you might want to include private init() { }, to make sure you never accidentally create a separate instance. That’s up to you.

Thanks! But then how do I make that print(queuing:) function work correctly with the first 2 solutions?

You’d need to make print(queuing:) an async method that will await OutputCoordinator.shared.prepare(outputLine: …). For a logging service, that might be overhead that you might not want to incur, especially if you’re likely to be calling this frequently from synchronous contexts. Yet another reason you might prefer the third option.

I don't want this to be async. I just want a class to keep all log messages in one string and then dump them when the command exits, rather than taking time between each operation to print something out. All this async bullshit is making that far more difficult than it needs to be, especially because this is a single-threaded command

Then like @Rob says, just mark it as a @MainActor and it will always run on the "actor whose executor is equivalent to the main dispatch queue."

Accepting this for suggestion #3

@RoyRodney but then whenever I try to prepare/print anything, the compiler requires me to mark that as async, which then requires I wrap it in a Task, which then adds unnecessary multithreading and no longer guarantees FIFO
